# How to deal with a serializer that needs context

Tags: python, django

I have a situation here where the serializer needs context, basically the request object.

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    distance_away = SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product

        fields = [
            'pk',
            'distance_away',
        ]

    def get_distance_away(self, obj):
        coordinates = self.context["coordinates"]
        distance_in_km = None

        if coordinates != 'null' and coordinates is not None:
            lat = float(tuple(coordinates.split(","))[0])
            lng = float(tuple(coordinates.split(","))[1])
            ....
```

This means I have to pass a context whenever I use or call the serializer. That's fine for normal drf views.

Now I am faced with a situation where I need to use the serializer in a `ModelObserver`

```
class MarketplaceConsumer(GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [HasApiKey]

    @model_observer(Product)
    async def marketplace_activity(self, message: ProductSerializer, observer=None, **kwargs):
        await self.send_json(message)

    @marketplace_activity.serializer
    def marketplace_activity(self, instance: Product, action, **kwargs) -> ProductSerializer:
        '''This will return the product serializer'''
       
        return ProductSerializer(instance, context={'request': self.request}).data
```

At this point I will get the following error which makes sense(self.request):

> 'ModelObserver' object has no attribute 'request'
> This ModelObserver is for handling channel websocket actions.

Is there any way to solve this situation?